# Both calling Stored Procedure and SQL expression having problems when mapped to POCO which is not a domain object

Tags: c#, sql-server, orm, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am using ORMLite from ServieStack to call one of the Soterd procedure that I have.

1. When I call the stored procedure natively in SSMS it returns 3 rows with all data correctly
2. However, when I call it from ORMLite, it basically returns List<> of 3 objecs however, everyproperty in that object is pretty much having default value telling me that mapping failed somehow.

I am using following code to call the store procedure:

```
 public List<DomainUserDto> CallDemoStoredProcedure(string id)
       {
           List<DomainUserDto> results = Db.SqlList<DomainUserDto>("TestJoinSupportForORMLite", cmd =>
           {
               cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               cmd.AddParam("UserId", id);
           });
           return results;
       }
```

Also, I was trying a SQL expression that goes with ORMLite and basically behaves in the same manner that my DTO is cnot mapped properly:

My SQL expression is as below:

```
 List<DomainUserDto> rows = Db.Select<DomainUserDto>(Db.From<DomainUser>().
                                                                        Join<Order>().
                                                                        Join<Address>());

           return rows;
```

Jus tas my stored procedure, it returns 3 rows. However, all the three rows has empty data meaning each property has default values and nothing is mapped.

while DomainUserDto looks like following:

```
public class DomainUserDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }           
        public string StreetName { get; set; }    
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }    
        public string Details { get; set; }
    }
```

Attached is the sample result from the stored Procedure:

[image]

Please note following things:

- There is not a single table in the Database that I can directly map to DomainUserDto
- When  I use the same functionality to map the object to a Domainobject with a table in Database, it work perfectly fine. It only fails when there is not a table in database which I can map to the POCO
- All the create scripts for all the tables involved and the stored procedure under concern are at following location:  gist.github.com/anonymous/ef54cc68dc9dd57ca6ef.

thanks

Comment: Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: What does the `DomainUser` POCO look like that you're trying to map from? Do the property names match? Can you provide a screenshot of the results that the Stored procedure returns, i.e. using SQL Management Studio?

Comment: @mythz: I just added snapshot from SSMS which contains the results from the Stored Procedure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From docs for using for [calling Stored Procedures using SqlList](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#stored-procedures-using-custom-raw-sql-apis), try instead calling your Stored Procedure with:

```
var results = db.SqlList<DomainUserDto>(
    "EXEC TestJoinSupportForORMLite @UserId", new { UserId = id });
```

The issue is because you're returning ProUser's `string Id` but your DomainUserDto is trying to coerce it into an `int` which prints the error out to the Console:

```
ERROR: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ToInt32(Object value)
```

It will work after changing it to a string as seen [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/a012d05b344edb61e2fbcb4e9b1cdad66ffa111b), e.g:

```
public class DomainUserDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
}

var rows = db.SqlList<DomainUserDto>(
    "EXEC TestJoinSupportForORMLite @Id", new { user.Id });

rows.PrintDump();
```

I'll look at adding an config option to OrmLite in future to throw an exception instead of logging for coercion errors so the exception is more visible.

Comment: I just tried that but it is still returning 25 elements with C# default values for each. From what I have observed, it sounds like it is getting all the elements correctly because it knows that there are 25 rows. However, mapping is failing silently somewhere.

Comment: @Californicated Weird, what's the best way for me to debug this locally? Could you put together (gist?) the SQL Scripts for creating the tables and an empty SP definition used.

Comment: I just created a Gist at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ef54cc68dc9dd57ca6ef. It has all three tables' create script and also the Stored Procedure.

Comment: @Californicated just tried this, the issue selecting `ProUser.Id` string into `DomainUserDto.Id` int, changing it will work.

Comment: Yes, it did work . Thank you so much. How did you get the detailed error in the console? I don't see anything in my output window?

Comment: @Californicated You probably don't have a [logger enabled](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Logging), try: `LogFactory.LogManager = new ConsoleLogFactory()`

Answer (score 0):

> When I use the same functionality to map the object to a Domainobject
>   with a table in Database, it work perfectly fine. It only fails when
>   there is not a table in database which I can map to the POCO

So, try creating a View corresponding to the columns you want and use that to map to the POCO.